# How to setup minimum permissions to create files from PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permissions

I am using PHP to create a file from an uploaded image like this:

```
$in = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempFile);
imagejpeg($in, "images/", 100);
```

This works perfectly only if I set the `images` directory to have **world write** permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 foo foogroup images
```

My `/etc/group` contains:

```
foogroup:5134:www-data
```

and when I run `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` on the web page I get `www-data`.

So why does `775` (**group write**) permission not work?

Comment: Keep permissions to 777 temporarily, and create one file. What owner and group is it created under? Try also using www-data instead of foogroup and a permission of 775. Does this change anything?

Comment: if I change the group to `www-data` that means all other users with groups similar to the `foogroup` will have access to the files. Images permissions `-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   130818 May 19 19:43 573e095cf2741.jpg`

Comment: I'm trying on a 14.04LTS and cannot reproduce this. What platform and version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my previous comments: your server is running with user `www-data` and group `www-data`. We know this, because when the file is created, it belongs to that user and group.

By rights, in Unix, this means that if the directory is owned by a group containing `www-data`, and the directory is group writeable, then the directory can be written by any user of group `www-data`.

Now we change the permissions from

```
775    www-data   foogroup
```

to

```
775    www-data   www-data
```

We may have two cases: it works, or it does not.

If it does not work, then we have a clear demonstration that it isn't the group that matters -- it must be the user. Which for our intent and purpose must therefore be something *different* from both `www-data` *and* `foogroup`.

If it works, it *probably* means that simply *belonging* to the group is not enough - the check which seems to be actually performed is more an *exact match* of the group.

What I'm suspecting is that your setup is not identical to mine (stock Ubuntu 14.04-LTS, I believe, with `mod_php5` under Apache), and you have some "security feature" in place which supplements, and in some cases in essence replaces, the Unix filesystem permission checking with some more stringent check of its own. *Then* if this test passes, operations are performed as usual as the user `www-data`.

So another test you could run is, both with your current non-working permissions and the working 777 permissions, execute

```
shell_exec("touch images/test.jpg 2>&1");
```

The output *might* yield some useful information. For example we might discover that the shell is actually run by another user (775 does not work, 777 does, but now the file is owned by someone else), or that the file that PHP cannot create *is* created from the shell invoked by that same PHP (this would conclusively demonstrate some sort of restraint in effect inside PHP).

Other useful information to have: are you running FastCGI, CGI, Apache module, nginx, other...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, check in the httpd.conf file what user and group apache is using. I fixed a similar issue by setting the user apache runs with to the owner of the directories.